# Difference Between Terminal and SSH Session

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

When I attempt to turn off time syncing in ubuntu 16.04, it is successful even though I am not running as root and the man page for timedatectl indicates that it should prompt me for authorization. Command:

```
timedatectl set-ntp off
```

However, if I ssh to the box using the same user, I get prompted:

```
ssh localhost
timedatectl set-ntp off
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-ntp ===
Authentication is required to control whether network time synchronization shall be enabled.
```

Does anyone know why I don't get prompted when running in a native shell? How can I configure my system to NOT prompt when I ssh? Thanks.

Note: I suspect this has to do with the credential keyring. I am still investigating and will update/close this question if I figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

While I was unable to figure out what is happening under the covers, I was able to work-around this issue by adding a sudo rule:

```
$USER ALL=(root) NOPASSWD :/usr/bin/timedatectl *
```

This allows me to use 'sudo timedatectl set-ntp off' without prompting for a password.